# PHP cURL CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION - Large files cause hang?

Tags: php, curl

I am not sure if hang is the correct term, but once the file is 100% uploaded my code after the upload code is not ran.

```
set_time_limit( 0 );
$fp = fopen( $zip_file, 'r' );

$curl_handler = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl_handler, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://upload-site/' . $zip_name . '.zip' );
                        curl_setopt( $curl_handler, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                                'requesttoken: ' . $request_token,
                                'authorization: Basic ' . $basic_authorization_token,
                        ] );
                        curl_setopt( $curl_handler, CURLOPT_PUT, true );
                        curl_setopt( $curl_handler, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize( $zip_file ) );
                        curl_setopt( $curl_handler, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp );
                        curl_setopt( $curl_handler, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false );
                        curl_setopt( $curl_handler, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, [ $this, 'updateUploadProgress' ] );
                        curl_setopt( $curl_handler, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0 );
                        curl_setopt( $curl_handler, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true );

                        $curl_retval = curl_exec( $curl_handler );

curl_close( $curl_handler );


//This code here is never ran on large file uploads.
```

Progress function (works)

```
    function updateUploadProgress( $curl_handler, $download_file_size, $downloaded, $upload_file_size, $uploaded ) {
        $progress = round( ( $uploaded / $upload_file_size ) * 100 );
        echo 'Uploading... ' . $progress . " / 100%\n";
    }
```

When uploading small files around 5mb everything works fine. But uploading a 500mb file after hitting 100/100 on the upload progress none of the code after curl_close() gets ran.

Comment: How long did you wait to come to the conclusion "This code here is never ran ..." ?  (/me curious)

Comment: 24 hours at the longest. Left it for a full day, the callback on upload progress also long stopped updating / being hit on my breakpoints.

Comment: What about [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) ? Does it have any special info ?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( But starting to think this might related to something else timing out? It's odd for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really a [mre], but I tried to get it to run on my local system.

(My PHP coding skills are low...)

I change the line: `$curl_retval = curl_exec( $curl_handler );` to:

```php
//$curl_retval = curl_exec( $curl_handler );
if(curl_exec($curl_handler) === false)
{
   echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl_handler);
}
else
{
echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

After `updateUploadProgress` was called multiple times, I did receive next message:

```
Curl error: Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused
```

This error is correct, because I am not allowed to upload to my local system ().

But I do ask meself which message you (@Midger) will be receiving ...